# Combobox Column DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I Added a combox column in my DataGridView.

I Fill it with information from a database for example

- INFORMATION 1
- INFORMATION 2
- INFORMATION 3

In all lines that return from the DataGridView in this combo box column.

The problem is when I get information from a database, let's assume that one of the returned items is a field that provides me the information that is related to the combobox, but I do not know how to let the combobox already selected according to the information I return from the database, for example, let's say my SELECT return 3 columns.

`[NAME]` , `[ID]` , `[INFORMATION]`

So I would like to let the combobox selected already according to the information that returned from the database.

Comment: What you want, what you have done and the exact problem you have now are not too clear. Can you please post your code (the select statement and the part where the combobox-type columns are added) and show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Should be done automatically as long as the value you retrieve from the database is available in the drop down list. Post the code where you add the data to the Grid.

Comment: Acutually I found out a way to do that.

Just need to edit the cell (where the combo box is) and attribute the value INFORMATION 1 for example, and then it select INFORMATION 1 in the combo box